# How to prevent dot underscore "._" files from being created after untar in tf.keras.utils.get_file()

Tags: tar, tf.keras

`tf.keras.utils.get_file(<directory_name>, <tgz path>, untar = True)`

How do I prevent the untar from the above get_file() call from creating duplicate "._*" files?

Answer (score 0):

I JUST figured it out for me, maybe it's the same for you. It wasn't the functions fault, but instead the files you are working with do in fact have files with ".*" as a prefix. For me, it was because I have a mac and in the image folders I zipped there are hidden mac files that have .* as a prefix.

I just rezipped my files using this command:
tar --disable-copyfile -czf weeds_image.tgz weed_images